# Error installing ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, rscript

I was trying to run a simple code on **ggplot2** and got the following error:

```
source("u1.txt")
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’


Error : package ‘foreign’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘maptools’
* removing ‘/home/shivangi/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/maptools’
* installing *source* package ‘multcomp’ ...
** package ‘multcomp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (multcomp)
ERROR: dependencies ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/home/shivangi/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/ggplot2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpOGWrr4/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘plyr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘reshape2’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘Hmisc’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘maptools’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages("ggplot2", dep = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error running ggplot this evening, essentially you need to try to install all the dependencies that failed. For me it was "scales", then "munsell" and then finally (the actual problem) "colorspace" which hadn't be updated since I upgraded to 3.1.1.  In your case, it looks like you want to first try installing "foreign" and then try ggplot2 again. Keep loading dependencies that error manually until you find the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the `install.packages()` call also install all dependent packages:

```
if(!require(ggplot2)) install.packages('dplyr',dependencies = TRUE)
```

the above code first checks to see if ggplot2 package is loaded, if not it tries to load the apckage. If it cannot load the package, it then tries to install the package and all of package its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

With RTools installed, I got this to work:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", type="source",dependencies = TRUE)
```

Compiled a few packages...

Make sure your PATH is updated to point to RTools properly, i.e. includes

```
c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin
```

at the front.

I am using Rtools32.exe