# Error installation R-packages on Linux Mint 18

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, r-package, r-car

It is somehow impossible for me to install new R-packages on my Linux Mint 18 system. I need to install `ggplot2` and `car`.
After the input

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

R is working for a very long time and after this, I get the output

> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
>   ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘plyr’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘tibble’, ‘lazyeval’ are not available for package ‘ggplot2’
>   * removing ‘/home/phine/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/ggplot2’
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>       ‘/tmp/RtmpsK4IjC/downloaded_packages’
>   Warnmeldung:
>   In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>     there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

The same happens, if I am trying to install the `car` package.

So far I was trying to follow the help from R-bloggers (https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/), but I get the same output.

Further I tried: ([Error installing ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726764/error-installing-ggplot2))

```
if(!require(ggplot2)) install.packages('dplyr',dependencies = TRUE)
```

The output is the same as above

> there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

After this I read the posts on this page ([Can't install R packages on Linux Mint 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793359/cant-install-r-packages-on-linux-mint-17)). 
After running in the terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
```

I get the output (this is a free translation. Unfortunately my terminal is speaking german, even if I change the system language to english)

> E: package »r-base-dev« has no installation candidate
>
> Input:sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpp
>
> Output:E: package r-cran-rcpp not found.

I hope my question is clear and precise enough. I am beginner in using R and Linux.

Comment: have you done sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade? Are these coming up with errors? I'm running Mint18 and have no problems with r installation. Do you have r-base installed? What does your /etc/apt/sources.list contain? Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631191/issues-in-installing-r-base-dev relate?

Comment: Have you check if you have `deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Note: `trusty` is for Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa. After that do `sudo apt-get update` then install `r-base-dev`. See more [here](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)

Comment: I included `deb https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/` to my `sorces.list`, ran the uptate and tried to install the r-base-dev again, but it dident work. My output looks exactly the same like here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631191/issues-in-installing-r-base-dev/41682646#41682646]. The problem is, that I really can't find this "Software Sources" window in Mint. Further I ran `sudo aptitude search r-base-dev` and there it seems, that r-base-dev already exists: `p   r-base-dev                      - GNU R installation of auxiliary GNU R pack`.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing after starting R in the vanilla mode:

```
$  R --vanilla
```

It is likely to work. If not post the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with Linux Mint 18.1 and tried to install ggplot2 package first time in my new installation of the R (3.2.3) and RStudio (1.0.136). Problem was solved when I installed `r-base-dev` via Software manager of the Mint.

Afterwards I have added cran to the `/etc/apt/sources.list` as *thecatalyst* suggest above.